# Sending Gmail as other user's in Workspace

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

#### Context

The company I work for is just now adopting a ticketing system for their IT help requests. Previously, all of our users have access to a Slack account and would start a message thread in an `itsupport` labeled channel to begin a "ticket". Now we would like users to send an email to an **itsupport@company.com** inbox which will then in turn create a ticket within the ticketing system.  Since we know our end-users are going to still send Slack messages in the channel, I have been tasked with making an integration between Slack and a Google inbox designated for our help desk requests. The ticketing system is managed by an IT company we are contracted with, thus I am not the one integrating the Google Inbox and the ticketing system. I am only tasked with the integration between Slack and the mailing inbox.

Not sure if this context is needed, but I am currently using Node.js to capture the requests sent from Slack and then using Nodemailer to send the emails into the **itsupport@company** inbox.

#### Problem

The problem I have ran into (I found some questions related earlier but am having a hard time finding them now) is figuring out how to send an email on behalf on any user within our Google Workspace. For example, if `Joe Schmo` sends a message in the correct Slack channel, I would like to be able to send an email to the **itsupport@company.com** inbox as **joe.schmo@company.com** rather than my personal Google workspace account or through a generalized IT user account. How would I achieve this goal? I could change the "From" name however it would be preferred if I could send the email from any email address in our workspace.

Comment: Have your workspace admin configure domain wide delegation for a service account for you.  The service account will then be able to send emails on behalf of Joe Schmo  to Itsupport