# Trouble sending emails using Nodemailer with a Google App Password

Tags: node.js, express, email, gmail, nodemailer

I am creating a route on an API which features sending an email when a user signs up. I am using nodemailer and google app password to achieve this. It was working perfectly until February 3rd 2023 that was the last use of the password. However, I did not change any code the connection simply just stopped working.

This is how my code is formatted:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
                pass: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD
            },

        });

        const mailOptions = {
            from: process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
            to: "user@gmail.com",
            subject: 'Test Email',
            html: "<h1>Email is sent<h1>"
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
```

I have also tried this format but it doesn't work either:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.gmail.com",
          port: 587, // or 465
          secure: true,
          auth: {
            user: process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD
          }
        });

        const mailOptions = {
            from: process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
            to: "user@gmail.com",
            subject: 'Test Email',
            html: "<h1>Email is sent<h1>"
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
```

In either case the error I receive after trying to send an email with either format is the following:

```
Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/workspace/elana-backend/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:787:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/workspace/elana-backend/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:773:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/workspace/elana-backend/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:232:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

The first block of code was working perfectly fine up until recently. I thought a possible password change may have revoked the app password because I noticed that in google app password documentation. Therefore, I also created a new app password but it still appeared with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit* -
*Are you using an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en&ref_topic=7189145) to make these requests? This password is used to connect applications to your Google account and WILL NOT allow you to login/authenticate with your Google account*

Have you tried using a service account with domain-wide delegation to send the email?

I use a similar piece of code to send emails (as users in our Google Workspace) when a Slack message is posted in a channel, however I struggled to have success authenticating using basic authentication like you are above. Instead I took a suggestion from `@Linda Lawton - DalmTo` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73974656/sending-gmail-as-other-users-in-workspace) question. Below I am using OAuth2.0 to impersonate a service account that is authorized through domain-wide delegation to send emails as users in the workspace. 
  Sample code:

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
   service: 'Gmail',
   auth: {
      type: 'OAuth2',
      user: process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
      //Derived from Service Account
      serviceClient: privatekey.client_id,
      privateKey: privatekey.private_key
   }
})
const mail_options = {
   from: process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
   to: 'test@gmail.com',
   subject: 'Test Mail',
   html: '<h1> Test Email </h1>',
}
transport.sendMail(mail_options, function(error, result){
   if(error){
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
   }else{
      console.log('Result: ' + result);
   }
   transport.close();
})
```

Google has some confusing, but well written documentation on using domain-wide delegation in your workspace [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=638116473054758805-551939111&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en#zippy=). If you are not familiar with Google Cloud services there might be some other resources to catch up on with as well 
You might also need to add the `transport.close()` method in the body of the callback in your `.sendMail()` method 
**References** 
[OAuth2.0 with Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount)
[Domain-Wide Delegation with Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)
[Domain-Wide Delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=638116473054758805-551939111&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en#start&setup&view)
[Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)